# django flatpage redirects

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

I want to make sure all of my flatpages have the `www` subdomain and redirect to it if they don't.

I've looked at some middlewares that redirect to `www`, but (1), they usually redirect all urls to `www` and (2), the ones I've found don't work with flatpages.

I don't want all of my site urls to redirect to include the www subdomain, just the flatpages.

Anyone know how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to modify a middleware, so that it only redirects if `response.status_code == 404`. Put the middleware just before the flatpage middleware in settings.py. This would redirect

```
http://example.com/flatpage/ -> http://www.example.com/flatpage/
```

but also

```
http://example.com/invalidurl/ -> http://www.example.com/invalidurl/
```

before returning a 404 error.

---

Another option would be to write your own flatpage middleware based on the official one. You can see the code for the `FlatpageFallbackMiddleware` class on the [django website](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/flatpages/middleware.py).

In the try, except block, check to see if a flatpage exists. Then redirect if appropriate. If you don't redirect, return the flatpage.

```
...
try:
    fp = flatpage(request, request.path_info)

    # Code to redirect to www goes here

    return fp
except Http404:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py file do something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^flat/(?P<static>.*)$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': 'http://www.mysite.com/flat/%(static)s'}),
    # other stuff
)
```

Comment: -1: This creates an infinite redirect. `mysite.com/flat/page` -> `www.mysite.com/flat/page` -> `www.mysite.com/flat/page` -> ...